# Make Bootstrap's navbar always collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The website I am working on does not use the Bootstrap navbar for desktop version, utilising the responsive navbar (and hiding the custom navigation) on the mobile version. The navbar, without the actual links, is present even in the desktop version, displaying the branding and the search form.

However, the problem is that the website ends up with three navigation types:

1) The custom navigation unit, used on the desktop version.
2) The collapsed navbar with a toggle button
3) The default "navigation links in navbar" on most of the tablets. I want to get rid of this one: there are too many links (can not do much changes to the website structure) and it looks noisy.

Is it possible Bootstrap's navbar always collapsed?

Comment: Can you post your navbar code?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I think it might help you resolve your situation.

Consider using the Bootstrap Responsive Utility classes to hide certain navigation elements. For instance, maybe apply the hidden-desktop class to the menu items inside the navbar.

Scroll to the bottom of this page to see the classes:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive